# click button get select box value in angular 2

Tags: angular

> Below is my .html code.

```
    <select class="form-control" id="location" required   [(ngModel)]="locations" name="location"  #location="ngModel">
      <option *ngFor="let location of locationType.locations" [value]="location.city_id"  >{{location.city_name}}</option>
</select>

  <button (click)='getFilterDetails(locations)'>Search</button>
```

and below is my .ts file code getting data from select box when click button

```
getFilterDetails(data){
```

console.log(data);
}

> Any body help how to get value of select box when click button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly get the value since you are using ngModel,

```
getFilterDetails(){
  console.log(this.locations);
}
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan-- it's working fine. it working like a charm